# converting vba array that returns a long number in excel to a string ie array (67, 1)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I am fledgling VBA macro user.

I have a macro that converts a txt file into specific length fields, and it all works fine.

However, one of those fields is always a 10 digit number.
When the macro runs, this number is converted into Excel, where the last few numbers are returned as zeros as Excel doesn't like long numbers (how infuriating).

What is the best way to convert an array as below into text/string before it gets into excel?

```vb
Array(53, 1), Array (67, 1), Array(77, 1)
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

In Excel, this would be something like `=text(Array(67, 1), "general")`.

I've tried `CStr(Array(67, 1))` & `String((10),Array(67, 1))` & `(Array(67, 1), As String)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. *where the last few numbers are returned as zeros as excel doesn't like long numbers* What value is it? Excel can work with several decimals, 15.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Format(Array(67, 1), String(10, "0"))
```

or, if decimals:

```
Format(Array(67, 1), "0." & String(10, "0"))
```

Comment: HI Thanks for the suggestion.  now I get the below error

Comment: Can't tell what it is.